# Firebase ignores Exclude on super class

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have those two files, One extends the other which is a base class with protected fields. The problem comes when i put Exclude on those fields but Firebase ignores the annotation and still put them on the server.

```
@Entity
public ClassOne extends BaseClass{}

public BaseClass
{
    @Exclude
    protected field; // Still get's recorded by firebase
}
```

What can I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firebase will accept `@Exclude` when your field is `public`. But in your case, it's `protected`. So, modifying your answer to have a public `@Exclude` method that returns your `private/protected` field's value will do the job:

```
public class BaseClass
{
protected Object field;
    @Exclude
    public Object getField() {
        return field;
    }
}
```

Comment: I just had the time to test it, even changing the access to the field to public, putting Exclude on the getter and on the field itself did not perform the job. Have you tested it and it worked for you?

Comment: Yes, I have and rerun the test just now. My field is even `private` and adding `@Exclude` to getter doesn't persist the data. Can you try creating a new project only firebase as a dependency to check if the problem is in your project or not? Also, your code is kinda pseudo-code, hopefully, your real code is not in Kotlin because in Kotlin annotations for Firebase is different from Java.

Comment: One more alternative, make your field public annotated with `@Exclude` and keep setter/getter but without `@Annotation`.

Comment: I have tried it all, none of them work. Even creating new project. My firebase-firestore version is `17.1.2`. Also, it's not Kotlin, just straight up java.

Comment: I don't know how is that possible. I've tested it in both `17.1.2` and `21.1.0` and worked as expected. If nothing works for you checkout from this repo. It simply puts one field and excludes the other one. I've removed `google-services.json` so just add your own and test if it works for you. https://github.com/mecoFarid/FirestoreExclusion.git

Comment: As it seems it's a local bug on my machine so it's not logical to keep this question active anymore, thank you for your efforts mate.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you would have a public getter for the `exclude` field. You would also need to add the @Exclude annotation to the getter for the `field` variable.

Comment: I have just done that and no success, have you tested it and it worked for you?